# Specify PHP version with PuppetLabs' Apache module

Tags: php, apache, puppet, puppetlabs-apache

I'm using [`puppetlabs-apache`](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-apache) to maintain my Apache installation. I want to specify the PHP version I'm using:

```
package { "php":
    ensure => "5.4.16"
}
```

But I get an error:

```
Duplicate declaration: Package[php] is already declared in file /path/to/my/server.pp ...
```

I can't find any documentation about how to specify the PHP version. It seems that the package is declared in [params.pp](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-apache/blob/master/manifests/params.pp), but it doesn't seem to allow you to change the version. So, short of hacking the module myself, how can I configure it to let me specify my own PHP package?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a collector, but it is a bit hacky... :)

You can use this anywhere in your code. (even other modules)

```
Package <| title=='php' |> {
  ensure => "5.4.16"
}
```

I haven't actually tried this, but it 'should' work...

http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/2.7/reference/lang_collectors.html

Comment: Cool! "A bit hacky" is better than what I'm using right now (which is _utterly_ hacky).
I'd never seen a collector, but often wanted something like that. I'll give it a go, and accept your answer if it works.